# Protect Wordpress against ddos attack

Tags: brute-force, ddos, blacklist, cpanel

[image]

The  above screenshot is from my website's cpanel visitors list.My website is build on wordpress. And I think someone is trying hard to crack open my website with DDOS attack and drain out my 10gb bandwidth in single night.Although I've applied `https` and blacklisted the repetitive ip address  accessing the non existing URL. What are the other possible methods to avoid this kind of attack ?

Comment: How many requests in total? My best suggestion would be to use for instance CloudFlare to handle caching.

Comment: HTTPS does nothing for DDoS or brute force

Comment: Why do you think this is a DDoS? What do you mean by 10gb bandwidth? How many IPs are making these requests?

Comment: @schroeder it might be brute force and DDOS at once as they are hitting non existing url repeatedly.

Comment: @vidarlo I agree with your Cloudflare recommendation. It comes with some prebaked Wordpress WAF rules and of course it is great at handling DDoS attacks and so on. So alot mote than just caching.

Comment: On your screen you can see that the user agent is bingbot, may be you can dig a bit, do you have evidences that you have been attacked with 10GB? if you show them will be good for us

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of possible ways to enhance the security of your site. But it depends on the architecture of your website, if it is a dedicated server or not.

1. Use anti-DDOS services- If you want free you can use Cloudflare. It will help you to block attacker requests, like botnet. Here's the link https://www.cloudflare.com/
2. Use Wordpress plugins to enhanced security - I used Wordfence, which includes an endpoint firewall and malware scanner that was built from the ground up to protect WordPress.
   https://www.wordfence.com/
3. Increase Internet Bandwidth and Server Capacity - The main reason your website can crash or go offline after a DDoS attack is if it doesn’t have the capacity to handle the volume of traffic sent by the attacker.